# Delphi BCD Field incorrectly displayed if DisplayFormat contains the dot

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firebird, dbexpress

I'm having a weird problem with an old project that's still being maintained with Delphi 7.

I have a TFMTBCDField component, representing Firebird Numeric Field (called GROSSPRICE).
It's value gets calculated on the server side (by the Firebird SQL server).
Due to a 27% tax rate the values are often like 4999.9999 that I'd like to display values rounded.

The strange thing is that if I set the DisplayFormat on that field to a value that has the dot inside (eg: '0.##') then 4999.9999 gets displayed as "5" (Should be either "5000" or "4999.99"). The same thing works with Currency fields as expected.

I have attached some images with examples as well. Do you know why is that happening, and (if possible) how to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It results in '4!' (including the exclamation mark)

Comment: Yeah, neither I've seen such thing yet. However BCD's often have something to surprise with :)

Comment: Since the app is in maintenance mode, you could just use the OnGetText  event handler of the field and format the text there...

Comment: This might be related to (http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2732). Do you have Delphi 7 update 1 installed?